# Disable touch events on screen while animation is playing

Tags: android, events, animation, view, touch

Hey I have a view with lots of child views which make some animations.

The problem is that when an animation is played, the views still react to touch events, which
is something that I don't want.

I thought about having transparent view on the top of all the views, that will be visible when
animation is being played

Is there other way to do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "OnAnimationStart"/"OnAnimationEnd" and define the touch behavior there.

Comment: I have lots of views and lots of animation listeners. That solution is too much work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a transaprent layout over the view(declare it in xml width and height fill parent)
and make  clickable true in animation start and clickable false in animation end.